# A very jumpy riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am the creator of five cent cigars,
>
> The creator of an American-Chinese dish.
>
> I am a Navy Rear Admiral,
>
> the creator of a programming excuse.
>
> But very simply, I am a container,
>
> A funnel for everyday objects.

**What/who am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> **a Hopper**

> I am the creator of five cent cigars,

> Edward **Hopper** created the painting *Nighthawks* of a corner diner at the top of whose sign is advertised "Only 5¢ — PHILLIES" *(cigars)*.

> The creator of an American-Chinese dish.

> Edward **Hopper** also created a painting called "Chop Suey".

> I am a Navy Rear Admiral,

> US Navy Rear Admiral Grace **Hopper**

> the creator of a programming excuse.

> Grace **Hopper** (yup, same one), per OP, "created the first compiler, and *compiling* is a programming excuse as shown in [xkcd #303: Compiling](http://xkcd.com/303/)."  (She also popularized the term "bug" in the programming sense, my original answer here.)

> But very simply, I am a container,
>   A funnel for everyday objects.

> A **hopper** is *a chute, box, or receptacle, usually funnel-shaped with an opening at the lower part*

And, finally, the title

> is itself, of course, a *jumpy* play on **Hopper**.

Comment: the programming excuse is actually a reference to xkcd

Comment: @bleh Huh. Which one?  (My answer here was just a coincidence then? Cuz ... well .. it completely works hehe)

Comment: Fine, ill give it to you- its a compiler, that chair-sword-fighting comic where the boss asks what they are doing, and he replies "Compiling!"

Comment: I believe you're referring to this one: http://xkcd.com/303/. The author of this webcomic is Randall Munroe.